# Oracle Apex how to find default login password

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I created a new application in apex and by default the login page got created.
Now when i run the application, what username and password should i put to enter?
I am confused as to which table stores the login and password.

The login page has itemsfor username and password and in processes uses apex_authentication.login(username item....& password item).

So how do i figure out what my username and password is?

This is my first time trying to create an apex application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you didn't create any additional users, then provide your **workspace**'s username and password.